# "Locally Cartesian" varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, classification

Differentiable manifolds can be described in terms of local charts to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and transition functions that are diffeomorphisms. Trying to put $\mathbb{A}^n$ (over an algebraically closed field, say) in place of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and isomorphisms of open subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^n$ in place of local charts of course will not reproduce all the algebraic varieties, even the nonsingular ones, as they have a rich local structure (the stalk of the structure sheaf at a point fully determines its birational equivalence class etc.).

My question is

> What about the varieties that *can* be described in this way? At least for the complete ones, is there a characterization or a classification?

Projective spaces and grassmannians belong to this class. Clearly they must be smooth, and birational to $\mathbb{P}^n$ ...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking which smooth, proper varieties have the property that every point has a neighborhood isomorphic to an open in affine space, or equivalently, the local ring of every point is a localization of a polynomial ring.  Obviously every such variety is rational.  Conversely, every rational variety of dimension 1 or 2 has this property.  But the last that I heard, this property is open already for rational threefolds, even for the blowing up of a curve in projective 3-space.

Comment: Isn't this already a good answer? Often I ask myself why comment-boxes are used for answers.

Comment: @Jason: I agree with Martin that you could post your comment as an answer.